# Prolog Refine ( to be used in a grammar to parse prop logic formula

Tags: prolog, logic

Below is my grammar to parse a propositional logic statement.
At the bottom is the error. I am going to presume this is because I am wanting to use the ( and ) as part of the language so they can be recognized but they're reserved?
Is there a work around?

```
distinguished(s).
s ---> op, vp, cp. % A formula consists of an opening phrase, variable phrase and closing phrase.

op ---> bracket.
op ---> neg, bracket. %This allows for any number of Not's before the opening bracket.
op ---> bracket, vp, cp.
op ---> neg, bracket, vp, cp.

vp ---> neg, sym. 
vp ---> sym.
vp ---> sym, conn, sym.
vp ---> neg, sym, conn, sym.
vp ---> neg, sym, conn, negg, sym.
vp ---> sym, conn, neg, sym.
vp ---> sym, conn, op.

neg ---> [¬]. %The not symbol from the keyboard.
neg ---> [¬], neg.

cp ---> [)].

sym ---> ["P"].
sym ---> ["Q"].
sym ---> ["R"].
sym ---> ["S"].

conn ---> [v]. %lower case V
conn ---> [^]. %The hat symbol on numeric 6.

bracket ---> ["("].
```

Loading error:

```
ERROR: c:/users/chris/dropbox/dissertation!/code/parser.pl:7:
        '$set_predicate_attribute'/3: No permission to modify static procedure `op/3'
ERROR: c:/users/chris/dropbox/dissertation!/code/parser.pl:8:
        '$set_predicate_attribute'/3: No permission to modify static procedure `op/3'
ERROR: c:/users/chris/dropbox/dissertation!/code/parser.pl:9:
        '$set_predicate_attribute'/3: No permission to modify static procedure `op/3'
ERROR: c:/users/chris/dropbox/dissertation!/code/parser.pl:10:
        '$set_predicate_attribute'/3: No permission to modify static procedure `op/3'
ERROR: c:/users/chris/dropbox/dissertation!/code/parser.pl:20:20: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: c:/users/chris/dropbox/dissertation!/code/parser.pl:21:20: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: c:/users/chris/dropbox/dissertation!/code/parser.pl:23:17: Syntax error: Illegal start of term
```

Comment: Can you pick a different predicate name versus `op`? `op` is a built-in Prolog directive and Prolog doesn't like you using it. Also, do you mean `-->` rather than `--->`?

Comment: I guess you should also change `sym ---> ["P"].` to `sym ---> "P".`

Answer (score 0):

Which Prolog are you trying this on? I get the following syntax errors on SWI-Prolog:

1. The use of `--->` instead of `-->` throughout the code snippet.
2. The unquoted closing bracket in line `cp ---> [)]`.
3. The undefined rule `negg`, probably a typo of `neg`.
4. Judging from your error output the term `op` is already defined elsewhere, renaming it should solve the problem.

Also, I don't get your use of `distinguished/1` at the top of the snippet.

To answer your main question: using the brackets `(` and `)` in your grammar seems fine to me. They should however be quoted. I'll include sample output I get when running your code after fixing the above syntax errors:

```
?- phrase(s, X).
X = ["(", ¬, "P", ")"] ;
X = ["(", ¬, "Q", ")"] ;
X = ["(", ¬, "R", ")"] ;
X = ["(", ¬, "S", ")"] ;
X = ["(", ¬, ¬, "P", ")"] ;
X = ["(", ¬, ¬, "Q", ")"] ;
X = ["(", ¬, ¬, "R", ")"] ;
X = ["(", ¬, ¬, "S", ")"] ;
X = ["(", ¬, ¬, ¬, "P", ")"] ;
X = ["(", ¬, ¬, ¬, "Q", ")"] ;
X = ["(", ¬, ¬, ¬, "R", ")"] ;
X = ["(", ¬, ¬, ¬, "S", ")"] ;
X = ["(", ¬, ¬, ¬, ¬, "P", ")"] ;
X = ["(", ¬, ¬, ¬, ¬, "Q", ")"] ;
X = ["(", ¬, ¬, ¬, ¬, "R", ")"]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you could see my answer to help :)
And is there a way to enter the equation without all the " " and ,'s.

Comment: This depends a bit on what you want the output to be like in the first place. Double quotes usually denote code lists in Prolog, except for SWI-Prolog >=7, where they denote strings. The semi-colon denotes logical disjunction. If you want to print in a human-readable format you can check out `format/2` and the like: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=format/2

Answer (score 0):

So finally got it working to parse a formula usaing the `phrase(formula, ["(","P",")"] ).`
However, is there a way to enter this without all the double quotes and semi colons?

```
formula --> opening, varphrase, closing. 

opening --> bracket.
opening --> negp, bracket. 
opening --> bracket, varphrase, closing.
opening --> negp, bracket, varphrase, closing.

varphrase --> negp, symbol. 
varphrase --> symbol.
varphrase --> symbol, conn, symbol.
varphrase --> negp, symbol, conn, symbol.
varphrase --> negp, symbol, conn, negp, symbol.
varphrase --> symbol, conn, negp, symbol.
varphrase --> symbol, conn, opening.

negp --> [¬], negp.
negp --> [¬].

closing --> [")"].

symbol --> [P].
symbol --> [Q].
symbol --> [R].
symbol --> [S].

conn --> [v]. %lower case V
conn --> [^]. %The hat symbol on numeric 6.

bracket --> ["("].
```

Comment: In this code snippet you fix some of the syntax errors, but you've introduced new ones as well. In Prolog, terms that start with a capital letter are variables. Your use of the singleton variables `P`, `Q`, `R`, `S` is probably unwanted.

Comment: I used capitol letters as that is what a user would expect to enter when typing in a formula as that is how they would write it down. if that makes sense?

Comment: But the capital letter only occurs once, so the variable instantiation is not used. In order to use the code that is parsed / that should be generated, you should parameterize the DCG rule, e.g. `symbol(X) --> [X].`